# python 2.7 and 3.3.2 ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, python-3.3

I have a Python program `MyFile.py` made in 3.3.2 version in Windows environment.

When I try to run it in my Ubuntu 13.04, I got:

> bash: ./MyFile.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I changed it with:

> tr -d '\r' < MyFile.py > MyFileLinuxVer.py

But I still get wrong output. It was correct output on Windows by using:

> python.exe -i MyFile.py Arug1 Argu2 Arug3...

of course in Ubuntu I used `./MyfileLinuxVer.py Argu1 Argu2 Argu3`

After I realized that I am running my program in python 2.7 in ubuntu, I installed Python 3.3.2 but I still don't know how to run it.

There is conflict. and I don't know what to do?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible issues:

1. Check and see whether you can run your interpreter. For example, if you have "/usr/bin/python" on your first line, try put that into terminal and see whether it brings up python. If not, replace the first line with "#!/usr/bin/env python";
2. Command-Line argument issues. You will need to re-check whether the arguments are correctly passed. Apparently, the argument count for "python.exe -i MyFile.py Arug1 Argu2 Arug3" is different from "./MyfileLinuxVer.py Argu1 Argu2 Argu3". Thus, there could be argument-misplacement issue.

Hope that helped!

Comment: hi Bill, Thank you. When I type /usr/bin/env python in my terminal, it directs me to python 2.7. I also tried to change the 1st line from !#/usr/bin/python to #!/usr/bin/env python, I still get the wrong output. HOwever, when I tried to type python3 before the file's name and the arguments. it giver me the correct output??? I dont know what is going on?????|

Comment: I am actually a biologist have little knowledge about python. I work  windows and ubuntu Linux. that is why the problems came up. is it possible to convert the python 3.3.2 code to 2.7?? is it easy or difficult?

Comment: @user2876177 The code is mostly compatible, and I think you just need to change the indexes when fetching arguments from the command line.

Comment: @user2876177 Or actually even easier, try to change the first line to "#!/usr/bin/env python3", and see whether that works.

Comment: Yesssssssssss that works. thank you...  but I still dont understand, why might have some indexes changes between different python versions?

Comment: @user2876177  I am actually not sure, because I am most familiar with Python 2.7...